# 1 continuous predictor and a 3 level ordinal outcome

Tags: regression, categorical-data, continuous-data, ordered-logit

I´m evaluating the impacts of logging in a forest, so my independent variable is the intensity of logging (i.e. trees per area) and my dependent variables are the injuries in the residual trees (the ones that are not logged). I have 3 intensities of injuries and a count data of number of trees with each intensity of injury. I was thinking in doing a logistic regression, but I don´t know if it fits my data nor how to use it in this arrangement of predictor x response.

Comment: The predictor is the intensity os logging in a sample area, and the outcome is the frequency of trees inside that sample area with each of the intensities of injuries. If I had only two samples I would use chi-square or Kolmogorov-smirnov test, but I have like 141 samples. So, maybe something like the poisson regression. But again, I´m completely new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [ordinal logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_logit).  This is a generalization of regular (binary) logistic regression in which you fit a model predicting the probability the response is $1$ vs. $>1$, and $1$ or $2$ vs. $>2$, etc., simultaneously.  All slopes are assumed to be the same, but you will have $k-1$ intercepts (thresholds) for $k$ categories.  You can find some tutorials for OLR for various software on [UCLA's statistics help site](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/dae/).

Comment: Thanks for your help, @gung. I have read the links you posted and I think that it may not be the solution. I think I did not made myself clear in the original post, but let me try to be more accurate. 
The predictor is the intensity os logging in a sample area, and the outcome is the frequency of trees inside that sample area with each of the  intensities of injuries. 

If I had only two samples I would use  chi-square or Kolmogorov-smirnov test, but I have like 141 samples. So, maybe something like the poisson regression. But again, I´m completely new to this.

Comment: That is OLR, @DanielAugustodaSilva. There is some question of how to set up your data to use it, though. You may need to create an individual row for each tree w/ the intensity of the injury as the response variable, rather than have your data in an aggregated format.